# Possible use maven to perform auto Java Class name replacement during compile?

Tags: java, maven

I notice after Java class compiled will generated ClassName.class file, however it can perform easy reverse engineer to get same source code.

May I know any way to replacing ClassName & variable to other automatically generated value?

Or other prevention method perform reverse engineer?

Thanks.

Comment: Just left me comments if my question not valid. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know code obfuscator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want an obfuscator, which will try to rename all your classes & methods to incomprehensible names, as well as often reducing file size by quite a bit. A popular (free and open source) one is ProGuard: https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard,